# netlify deploy issue, "build.command" failed

Tags: netlify

[image]

help please I keep on getting this error and I don't know what's wrong first I use the npm run build then it gave me the same error then I watch YouTube and change it to CI= npm build but this error is still showing up, how can I fix this?

Comment: This information is not enough. Can you please paste your package.json file code here ?

Comment: This information is not enough. Its says `npm not able to find a file` but do not know which one. Can you run the production build of website locally and paste the output here and also the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

got exactly the same error for many times. And tried the same things. If anyone can help I guess we all appreciate it.
Below you can find my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "cryptocheck24",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.10",
    "@portabletext/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@sanity/client": "^3.3.6",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",
    "flowbite": "^1.5.3",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.1.11",
    "groq": "^2.29.3",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tippy.js": "^6.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "eslint": "8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```